# Do keypad commands come from Android or the manufacturer?

Tags: dialer-codes

I'm curious if keypad commands like those listed below come from the Android OS or if they're added by manufacturers. On my N1, I know of these two commands:

`*#*#checkin#*#*` - Phones home to check for updates.

`*#*#info#*#*` - Enters a detailed phone information menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many that seem to be "standard", but they can also be added by individual applications (e.g. provider-installed).

Check out http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=540483 for a method to extract telephony codes from your installed apps.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! So the real answer is the codes come from APKs, which will vary by device.

Comment: Yup, you got it!

Answer (score 0):

I entered *#*#info#*#* on my Captivate and got to the same menu.

So, in the interest of adding to the list

*#*#1472365#*#* gets you to the GPS configuration menu (not sure what word that works out to)

Comment: No, `*#*#1472365#*#*` doesn't work on the Nexus One

Comment: So that leads me to think the commands come from the manufacturer? HTC has different commands than Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

It's android based, I tried same commands on Moto Droid and HTC myTouch, both worked exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try the *#*#1472365#*#* command that Dr.Dredel mentioned?

Comment: Yup, doesn't work on myTouch. I don't have the Moto Droid on me so I can't try it. I guess that's not android default??